# Excel vba combobox - white spaces after item's name

Tags: sql-server, excel, combobox, vba

I have created a userform with mutliple comboboxes. User can either pick item from the list or type in a new item. The list is filled with data selected from a database (MS SQL 2012). Userform then executes a stored procedure and inserts data to tables in database.

When the item is chosen from the list, it's highlited in blue and there are some white spaces after the item. I have no idea where they came from and how to get rid of them. I've inserted some items directly to database so there shouldn't be any spaces. I added also some by using the userform and shouldn't be any either. Here's a print screen how it looks like:

[image](http://i61.tinypic.com/2qn2rma.jpg) (too little reputation for posting images)

The code I am using to fill combobox:

```
    Private Sub cboImię_Enter()


On Error GoTo Combobox_Initialize_Err

    Dim rsImię As New ADODB.Recordset

    rsImię.Open "SELECT DISTINCT Imię FROM Osoba;", con, adOpenStatic

    If rsImię.RecordCount = 0 Then
        cboImię.AddItem
            ElseIf cboImię.ListCount = 0 Then
                rsImię.MoveFirst
                With Me.cboImię
                    Do
                        .AddItem rsImię!Imię
                        rsImię.MoveNext
                    Loop Until rsImię.EOF
                End With
            Else: GoTo Combobox_Initialize_Exit
    End If

Combobox_Initialize_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsImię.Close
    Set rsImię = Nothing
Exit Sub

Combobox_Initialize_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
        rsImię.Close
        Set rsImię = Nothing
        con.Close
        Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'd be grateful for any tips how to avoid those white spaces.

Comment: Could you share the schema of the table that the data is coming from?

Comment: In this case it's a simple Person table with only ID and person's name:
http://i58.tinypic.com/2ij2c1x.jpg
For other comboboxes tables have multiple columns but I select data from one column only

Comment: Sorry i mean what type is the name field in the table ie `nchar` etc

Comment: Hell yeah, you got it. It's the data type: 
`CREATE TABLE dbo.Osoba
(
Osoba_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
Imię CHAR (8) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (Osoba_ID)
);`

Comment: Should be `varchar` or `nvarchar`. In other combobox I have the same problem and the data type is `nchar`.

Answer (score 1):

`nchar` and `char` both pad the strings in you table.

Change the data type to `nvarchar` or `varchar` to resolve the issue.

Note you'll need to amend the previous data in the table to remove the padding.